# Windows 10 Search menu keeps refreshing and not showing results

Tags: windows-10

I'm having a rather vague issue where my Windows 10 search is constantly refreshing (or so it seems).

My workflow includes commonly pressing the Windows key, followed by typing the first 3-4 characters of a program I need, pressing enter, and being able to continue. Half of the time, this works, but if I type 3 characters and I need to see which results come up, I won't see any, thus not being able to pick the right program.

[Here's a video of the problem](https://0x.ms/EUuDAjXge1u)

I've already ran the troubleshooter for search from the settings app, but this didn't work

I'm running Windows 10 Pro, version 2004, OS build 19041.388.

Answer (score 0):

This advice for resetting Windows Search applies to Windows 10 version 1903 and later.
It uses Windows PowerShell and requires administrator permissions.

- Download from Microsoft the script
  [ResetWindowsSearchBox.ps1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/100295)
- Right-click the downloaded file select "Run with PowerShell"
- If asked "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?," select Yes
- When the word "Done" appears, close the PowerShell window.

If you receive an error message saying
"Cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system",
run the following command in the PowerShell window and then repeat the above:

```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Press "Y" if you receive a warning message to accept the change.

To revert to your previous setting PowerShell execution policy of Restricted,
use the command:

```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

If your organization has disabled running scripts, contact your administrator.

Source:
[Microsoft Fix problems in Windows Search](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520146/fix-problems-in-windows-search)